# Reasons for declined not-an-answer flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer

I know that this has been asked other times, but I'd like to know why the "not an answer" flag was declined for this **specific** answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725928/2055152

I even left a comment below to explain, and from my point of view that can in no way be considered an answer to the original question.

Comment: It *is* an answer. A poor one, but it is an answer.

Comment: @Joe No, it does not attempt to answer the question. It says to use something else, when the question is looking for a tutorial/documentation.

Comment: It's asking for a recommendation, and that's a recommendation.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask about an alternative resource.

Comment: "It doesn't ask about an alternative resource." Absolutely true. From an uninformed user's view (like my comment above), it is a borderline-answer because it seems to _attempt_ to answer the question. However this seems like an edge case that needs to take the tech topic into consideration.

Comment: The question has been deleted by moderation. If we want to have any more discussion about it someone should put the question/answer text in this post.

Comment: @Scimonster: *that is still an attempt at an answer*. It doesn't ask a new question. It doesn't contain nonsense. It doesn't say 'look at this question instead, it'll answer yours'.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370

Comment: The link in this question is dead.  It seems the question was removed.

Answer (score 17):

I declined it because it addresses the question. It's an extremely poor answer, but *it is* an answer.

The whole question can be nuked.

Comment: I still think it doesn't address the question in any way. The question is about generating primes in OpenSSL. If the OP realized that another tool is good for the purpose, that doesn't change the question. An answer would be something like "In OpenSSL you generate primes with this command: `command`"

Comment: @Numbers If the OP asks how to drive a screw into a board with a hammer, is it inappropriate to say "Use a Drill"?

Comment: Yes, it was an extremely poor answer, as George notes, @Numbers. If it had been posted to a reasonable question, fixating on it as a problem would make sense - but, it wasn't. If a problematic question attracts problematic answers, there's a much more thorough solution to the root problem that doesn't involve trying to garden the answers - and George implemented that solution.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I still not completely agree: the question, although poor, still makes sense ("teach me how to read the OpenSSL man", if you want). However I get your reasoning and I hope I can raise better flags in the future.

Comment: @Numbers Everyone gets declined flags. I have over 40 declined flags. The important thing is to focus your flagging energy on the root problem; and not necessarily on a symptom. In this case, the question really needed to be flagged and closed; or a custom flag on the answer to the effect of, "This answer provides no information because the question itself is a recommendation question from 2 years ago that doesn't have any other answers. Should be nuked."

Comment: I'm not sure that's actually what the question was asking, but if you thought it was then you could've edited it to actually say that - and *then* flagged the answer, @Numbers. Point is, deal with the root problem first - if the question is bad, don't waste time on the answers; either fix the question and *then* fix the answers, or delete the question *since that also deletes the answers!*

Answer (score 5):

Why was your flag rejected rather than accepted? Because both would have been equally right; it was a toss-up, not worth much reflection or hand-wringing.

I say, address the root cause instead:

**Crap questions attract crap answers like turds attract flies.**

When I review, I often find myself hesitating; this answer is *so bad*, does it really qualify as an answer? Then I look at the question and go, ah, that's what's going on. Then I vote to obliterate the entire Q&A in one fell swoop instead.

You can debate endlessly — with others on meta, or on your own when about to cast a flag — whether a terrible post is on one or the other side of the fuzzy scatological smear that separates barely-arguably-answers from not-quite-arguably-answers. Witness the comments to this meta Q&A. Is such debate useful? Not particularly.

Instead, next time you face a similar situation, flag the question. It's a clear-cut case, it will get acted upon, and it will be useful.